# How to get the second set of values in li using xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

```
<div id="test"><div class="contains"><ul class = "value"><li> 1 </li><li> 2 </li><li> 3 </li></Ul></div></div>

<div id="test"><div class="contains"><ul class = "value"><li> 1 </li><li> 3 </li><li> 6 </li></Ul></div></div>
```

Please help me...

Here i need to select any value from the second list of li. All the attributes div with ID and class are of same. im unable to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure it will always be the second list of `li`, more acurately the LIs in the UL from the 2nd , you can select these with `[2]` to select the 2nd `div` with `id=test` (by the way, 2 elements should not share IDs...)

```
./div[@id="test"][2]/div[@class="contains"]/ul[@class="value"]/li
```

Comment: This worked for me as well `"//*[contains(@class, 'ember-power-select-options')]//li[2]"`